# Comparing two dump files for report on objects with highest growth

Tags: windbg, sos

For debugging managed applications If I have two dump files, is there anyway to compare these two file? I am thinking about the scenario of memory leaks and if I take process snapshots at different time, I was wondering if there are anyways of automatically comparing the files and get some type of report on which object has largest growth in count and/or size. I know you can generate these type of reports  via ANT memory profiler but looking for any free tools/scripts for this purpose.

Comment: Check if this article helps.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9008065/automating-windbg-or-otherwise-extracting-information-from-dump-files

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Can you use `!dumpheap -stat` and compare the results using a powershell script?

Comment: i don't know much abuot powershell with windbg. Anyone knows if its possible to do?